# Type of reference cannot be used in a conditional formatting formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to highlight cells on B column that contains text from A column. Therefore only cells B11:B13 should be highlighted. I'm clueless how.

Here goes:

```
     A
1 John Doe
2 Jane Doe
3 Uncle Sam

     B
11 John Doe
12 Jane Doe
13 Uncle Sam
14 Meow Zedong
15 Genghis Khan
```

The conditional formatting (text contains, A1:A3) should highlight cells in B.
However, it only works for a single cell. So I'll have to manually use text contains for each cell on A column.

I've tried to force it with new rules and dabbled a little bit with VBA with no luck. The things I've tried always produce the error:

> Type of reference cannot be used in a conditional formatting formula

Answer (score 0):

Select column B and create a [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) rule based on the following formula.

```
=isnumber(match(b1, a:a, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not working. I highlighted the column, created a new formula based on the one you provided but nothing was highlighted.

Comment: @LSX When you select the B column, make sure the top cell is the active cell.  By default it will have a white background where the rest will have a grey background.  When you make your formula, make sure to change B1 to the row of the active cell.